# Customer information wrong in REST API Magento 2

Tags: customer-account, magento2.2.8

Recently we have upgraded from Magento 2.2.2 commerce to Magento 2.2.8 commerce

In the latest version we are facing issue with `/V1/customers/me` REST api call.
This call not return the correct user details. The model function not even called some time though we change the customer token values.

Looks like this method cached somewhere and returns different results for different users.

Anybody faced this kind of issue?

Comment: Please check the token of the customer.

Comment: token is different for every customer. It not even hitting the function for every request

Comment: Yeah of-cause it is different, I am saying that please regenerate that specific customer's token and check the values of customer/me API and compare it with Database.

Comment: yes both are same. Issue here is it not even accessing the function every time. It works fine in local. Issue occurs in our staging environment. But 2.2.2 version magento staging we don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the `Varnish`. When we disable varnish and check, this issue is not happened.

But we are still clueless why this GET method alone having this issue, other GET methods works fine with Varnish.